# Parsing HH:mm (with two digits minute) to LocalTime with JodaTime

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, jodatime

I need to parse a string like "10:10" and create a LocalTime object.
If the string is like "10:1" the parsing should throw a IllegalArgumentException. (minute must be of two digits)

So I made this

```
String time = "10:1";
LocalTime myLT;
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
myLT = dtf.parseLocalTime(time);
```

I tried also with DateTimeFormatter

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendHourOfDay(2)
.appendLiteral(":").appendMinuteOfHour(2).toFormatter();
```

but "10:1" is still converted...how to do it?

Comment: I don't want to check the length of the string.

Comment: checking the right format without checking the length is doing extra work for no reason. Why would you want to continue if length != 5? That is not just the simplest way the most efficient. Length = 5 must be your precondition.

Comment: I am partially agree @blade. With only the DateTimeFormatter I can check all the condition. Maybe is a litter slower but imho is more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `appendFixedDecimal` method of [DateTimeFormatBuilder](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html). You pass the `numDigits` arguments which is a fixed number of digits instead of minimum required.

In your case it would be something like (haven't tested it myself)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendFixedDecimal(DateTimeFieldType.clockhourOfDay(),2)
    .appendFixedDecimal(DateTimeFieldType.minuteOfHour(),2)
    .toFormatter()
    .withZoneUTC();
```