# How to compare if a timestamp falls in range of a given time period in Java

Tags: java, calendar, jodatime

In my `Java Spring MVC Web Application`, I am trying to write a program to save some data with a time stamp along with it. But I have a specific time period which I have to exclude.

For example, I have the following timestamp: `Sat Jul 28 17:03:00 IST 2018` which is a Java Date object. Before saving to the database I have to check if this time comes inside a specified range if then I have to get the next minute after the end of the time range.

But the time range is a string of the following format:

```
String startTime =  "5:03 PM";
String endTime = "5:10 PM";
```

So my if my timeStamp falls in between this time, my timestamp should be updated as `Sat Jul 28 17:11:00 IST 2018`.

I am finding now way to compare the two-time values since one is a string and the other is a time stamp.

Is there any way to convert `String endTime = "5:10 PM"`; to `Sat Jul 28 17:11:00 IST 2018` or just compare the time part, calculate the difference in minutes and add that to the timestamp.

Comment: From where do you have the values `startTime` and `endTime`? Is it a user input?

Comment: Do you already know the "new" (as of java 8) time API? See e.g. [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) and [Period](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Period.html)

Comment: @Lino , those are user inputs, i can only collect them as string

Comment: @Hulk, i use java 7. I usualy use joda for datetime related operations

Comment: For calculating a `Duration` between `DateTimes`: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851934/how-to-find-difference-between-two-joda-time-datetimes-in-minutes/12852021)

Comment: Assuming your `Strings` contain local times, [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106665/parsing-hhmm-with-two-digits-minute-to-localtime-with-jodatime) about parsing `LocalTime` might help.

Comment: @Hulk I do not see how `Duration` applies here. That class represents a span-of-time not attached to the timeline.

Answer (score 5):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Avoid the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`. Use only *java.time* classes. Likewise, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project too is now supplanted by the *java.time* classes, both having been created by the same man, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen).

### `Instant`

Convert your `Date` to [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). Both classes represent a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), always in UTC, despite the [`Date::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString()) method lying to you.

Convert using new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

Apply a time zone or offset-from-UTC for the wall-clock time intended by you pair of time-of-day strings. Did you mean 5 PM in New York, or 5 PM in Tunisia, or 5 PM in India?

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;  // Or "Pacific/Auckland" etc. 
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract the time-of-day without date and without zone.

```
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime() ;
```

### `LocalTime`

Parse your limits as `LocalTime` objects.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "h:mm a" , Locale.US ) ;

LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse( "5:03 PM" , f ) ;
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.parse( "5:11 PM" , f ) ;
```

### Half-Open

Generally best to use Half-Open approach to defining a span of time. This means the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So test for “less than eleven past five” if you want to exclude all of the tenth minute.

Tip: A shorter way of saying “Is equal to or is after” is “Is not before”.

```
if ( ( ! lt.isBefore( start ) ) && lt.isBefore( stop ) ) {
    zdt = zdt.with( stop ) ;  // Change to a different time-of-day. 
}
```

If that time-of-day on that date in that zone is invalid, the [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class makes an adjustment as needed.

### Database

For saving to a database in a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, let's adjust our moment into UTC by extracting an `Instant`.

```
Instant instantForDatabase = zdt.toInstant() ;
…
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instantForDatabase ) ;
```

Retrieval from database.

```
Instant instantFromDatabase = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
ZoneId zMontreal = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  // Or "Asia/Kolkata" etc.
ZondDateTime zdtMontreal = instantFromDatabase.atZone( zMontreal ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of options, one of the simpler is:

1)- You could convert the TimeStamp to a LocalDateTime/Calendar object and then get the hour and minute.

```
LocalDateTime localdt = sqlTimestamp.toLocalDateTime();
int hour = localdt.getHour();
int minute = localdt.getMinute();
```

2)-Then you can parse the string and compare the results.

-
You could also convert the strings to timestamp, for that you would need the start and end of day and to parse the strings.

-
Nonetheless, it sounds like the data types you selected will bring trouble later.

Comment: This Answer does not address the crucial issue of time zone.